# show different video when user visit second time

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a background video on my website. I have 5 different videos for header that I want show user when he visits second, third time and so on. After that, when he visited 5 times, the video will not be shown anymore, just an image on background.

I have video name like header-1.mp4, header-2.mp4, header-3.mp4 etc.

The following is my html code

```
<div class="fullscreen-bg">
    <div class="overlay"></div>
    <video loop muted autoplay class="fullscreen-bg-video" id="header_vid">
        <source src="videos/header-1.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        <source src="videos/header-1.webm" type="video/webm">
        <source src="videos/header-1.ogv" type="video/ogg">
    </video>
</div>
```

Comment: you can save played video url,name or any unique info in cookies,local storage etc.Every time you have to check saved data first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use cookies to count the user's visit.
Store a cookie named visit count, in that store the count.
So if user comes first time store a cookie with visitCount = 1 and show header-1.mp4.
If visitCount = 1 then the visit is 2nd time of that user, at that time show header-2.mp4 and so on!

**NOTE:** Cookies are not that reliable as they are stored in browsers, so if someone clears the cookies of the browser, according to this logic your code will play header-1.mp4 as you no longer have reference to the visitCount.

Comment: can u please make fiddle for me

Comment: u can give me any use  link too Thanks

Comment: I am also learning this thing with jquery, but here is one plugin which might be useful and a stack answer also:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458724/how-to-set-unset-cookie-with-jquery

https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie

Comment: I hope this helps :) @IsmailFarooq

Comment: Thanks Man :)

Thank u for helping this is working for me